# How to Turn Off Custom Functions in Canon Film SLRs

Tags: canon, autofocus

So I adjusted the Custom Function settings in the dial, and then I noticed that my Autofocus is now controlled by the CF button. I am using a Canon EOS 50, a 1995 film camera (not 50D).

How do I turn off that Custom Function and go back to the normal autofocus behavior (a slight press on the shutter button adjusts the autofocus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've changed the value for custom function 4 to "1" instead of "0".

To change them, you should turn the command dial to CF, then turn the main dial to the relevant position, before pressing the */CF button to change the value -- then the */CF button should behave as exposure lock again in normal shooting.